# how to mount/umount folder with bindfs/fusermount from root account without privileges?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, mount

This is my bash script into `init.d`:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
  'start')
    # mount
    bindfs -n /home/my_user/.local/share/Cryptomator/mnt /home/my_user/drivefolder
 ;;
  'stop')
    fusermount -u /home/my_user/drivefolder
 ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 { start | stop }"
 ;;
esac
```

so i run it from root account:

```
/etc/init.d/drivemount.sh start
/etc/init.d/drivemount.sh stop
```

What I want is to mount/umount `/home/my_user/drivefolder` from `root` account to `my_user` account **without privileges** (so that the mounted folder can be manipulated without privileges).

is there any way to do this? (without having to run the script in `my_user` account without privileges and from another location)

**Clarification**: The script does not run automatically. What I want is to run the script manually, either from `root` or from `my_user` with `sudo` only from `/etc/init.d` location (for reasons unrelated to the question)

PD: I have read that with `eval` it can be done but I don't know.

Comment: So you want to run `bindfs` as `my_user`? Doesn't `sudo -u my_user bindfs …` work?

Comment: yea. What you say is correct (I suggest you post the full answer), but I add something to it. If I run the script with sudo then I have to use eval `sudo -u my_user bindfs bla bla`. But it would be necessary to correct the command for umount

Comment: I thought the script is in `/etc/init.d/` so it runs automatically.Therefore I don't understand "if I run the script with `sudo`". Why do you want to run it with `sudo`? Doesn't it run as root automatically? And I totally don't get this "eval" idea. As for unmounting, I think root can `fusermount -u` anything without `sudo`.

Comment: It does not run automatically. I can program it in cron or run it manually from root or with sudo

Comment: So `/etc/init.d/` is misleading.

Comment: "from `my_user` with `sudo`" -- Why with `sudo`? The whole point seems to be you want to do something as `my_user` without elevated privileges. My solution in the first comment is simple and (IMO) so obvious. For this reason I did not post an answer, it seemed too easy, I suspected there was something more. And now it seems there is something more, but frankly I don't understand what it is. If you put `sudo -u my_user ` before `bindfs` in the script, then what exactly is the problem when you run the script as root or the user (with or without `sudo`)?

Comment: your answer is correct (add `sudo -u my_user` to mount and umount commands). The problem with your answer is that it is a bash script that is run from `root` or with `sudo ./script.sh` so there is duplicate `sudo`

Comment: Why is this a problem? `sudo` is the right tool to "change identity". If you need to change it twice then you need two `sudo`s.

Comment: If you claim that this is the right way (and that it is good practice), I suppose it is. Obviously I would not know if your answer is correct or not (that's why I asked the question. because I don't know the answer). Post it, for other users to review and confirm, then I will select it as the correct answer

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Should I use `sudo` in a script or `sudo` an entire script?](https://superuser.com/q/1255613/432690) I assumed you know what you want. If you really want to run `sudo ./script.sh` and then drop privileges inside the script then you need `sudo` or something similar in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `bindfs …` use `sudo -u my_user bindfs …`.

If root runs the script then `sudo` should allow becoming my_user without password. If my_user runs the script then `sudo` should allow becoming the same user without password. If any user runs the script with `sudo` then it will be as if root run the script.

<sup>(*Maybe* some settings in `sudoers` can change this behavior regarding passwords. I don't know for sure. I expect the common sane configuration to behave as described though.)</sup>

My tests indicate root doesn't need `sudo -u my_user` before `fusermount -u`. However if another user simply runs the script (without `sudo`) and they are able to authenticate as my_user then they will be able to mount. For consistency it will be good to allow them to unmount in the same way, so `sudo -u my_user` before `fusermount …` may be a good thing.